# C++ input goes wrong

Tags: c++, algorithm, input, stdin

I'm solving uva problem and trying to input series of Strings. The problem is when I try to input Strings in While loop, first input goes fine. But after that, the first character of each string is ignored. so I used __fpurge() function and it worked well. but I cannot use that function in uva Online Judge site. how can I replace __fpurge function?

```
char crypt_text[MAXLEN]


 int main()
    {
        char alphabet['z'+1], cryptchar['z'+1]; 
        std::cin>>n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        std::cin>> dictionary[i];
    while(1)
    {
        __fpurge(stdin);
        std::cin.getline(crypt_text,MAXLEN,'\n');
        if(cin.eof()) break;
        for(int i=0; i<'z'+1; i++)
        {
            alphabet[i] = '\0';
            cryptchar[i] = '\0';
        }

        if(!crypt_kicker(0,alphabet,cryptchar)) print_asterisk();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++, why are you doing such ugly thing with `char []`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Why do you use `'z' + 1` as size of the arrays? How much do you think it is?

Comment: I have to access array item by alphabet character. It works well just focus on my input problem please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problems lies in `__fpurge`

> For input streams
>   this discards any input read from the underlying object but not yet
>   obtained via getc(3);

Maybe this resolves your problems. Here is a more C++-ish way of handling the input.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    // declare dict, whatever it is
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cin >> dictionary[i];

    const std::size_t len = 'z'+1;
    std::array<char, len> alphabet;
    std::array<char, len> cryptchar; 

    std::string crypt_text;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, crypt_text))
    {
        std::fill(std::begin(alphabet), std::end(alphabet), 0);
        std::fill(std::begin(cryptchar), std::end(cryptchar), 0);

        if(!crypt_kicker(0,alphabet,cryptchar))
            print_asterisk();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if you really want `len = 'z'+1` instead of `len = 'z'-'a'+1` (no ending `'\0'` needed with `std::array`)

Comment: I there are too many other functions in my program so I have to use crypt_text as char[]

Comment: Then use a `std::string buffer` and `std::copy_n(std::begin(buffer), MAXLEN-1, crypt_text)`

Comment: And if it is only about passing a `char*` as argument, use `crypt_text.c_str()`.

Comment: what is the function copy_n? it doesn't exists in std

Comment: I am using C++11. Here is the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

Comment: You can achieve the same with `std::copy(std::begin(buffer), std::begin(buffer)+MAXLEN-1, crypt_text)`. But i would rather use the `c_str()` function.

Comment: @JunsungChoi `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: I can't use C++11 right now. I think there should be something more simple way to solve the problem.

Comment: Most of the things work without C++11. Just use plain C-arrays again and you are good to go.